# compare the value of first column in one file with the value in the first column of another file

Tags: bash, shell

I want to compare the value of first column in one file with the value in the first column of another file and if they are equal print the second variable of the second file

Example

file 1:

```
1 abc def
2 ghi mnk
```

file 2:

```
1 ahg aed asey dse wdr
2 cdh det det chde jdjj
5 drh detr the deasd
```

after comparing i want the output as

```
ahg
cdh
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you've tried and what, specifically, you're having problems with?

Comment: show your attempts..

Comment: You could use `awk`, or `join` with ease.  Other tools are probably harder.  Using `join` requires the data in sorted order — what you show counts as sorted, but you might have more work to do if you have hundreds or thousands of lines.  What should happen if there are 3 lines in the first file with column 1 set to 99 and there are 4 lines in the second file with column 1 set to 99?  Or is that absolutely not possible?

Comment: In my first file first variable will be a numeric number and in my second file i have to compare the numeric number variable in the first file with the second file and if they are same i want the second variable to be printed as output.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are sorted, you can use `join`:

```
join file1 file2 -o2.2
```

`-o` specifies the output format, in this case the second column of the second file.